# how to print number of stars depending on user choose

Tags: java, printing, interactive

I've been trying practiceIt problems and expand them a little - and I'm stuck.
The code will give results in as many stars as it's necessary, but I do not know how to make user decide the value for n.

I've tried adding to both methods (main/starString) those code lines:
 "Scanner input = new.Scanner(System.in); 
int n = input.next();" [also input.nextInt]

but the code will note allow any input from console. Not to mention I've got no idea where shoud I add second println command to actually print result from this code... 
help me please

```java
import java.util.*;
public class printStars {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        System.out.println("choose number and I wil show you 2^number stars");

    }
        public static String starString(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            } else if (n == 0) {
                return "*";
            } else {
                return starString(n - 1) + starString(n - 1);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Choose number and I wil show you 2^number stars: ");
        System.out.println(starString(in.nextInt()));
    }

    public static String starString(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return "*";
        } else {
            return starString(n - 1) + starString(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Choose number and I wil show you 2^number stars: 5
********************************
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like a charm! So to be absolutely sure what happened: First we added scanner in main. Then we added println on the last line in main, and this println called a string from next method and set this string's value from the start. Do I understood this correctly?

Comment: You are most welcome. Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be checking the input before you enter the method.  Here is one approach that allows for improper input and reprompts the user to enter the correct value.  This way, no exceptions need be caught.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String prompt = "Choose number (or a char to end) \nand I will show you 2^number stars: ";
        System.out.print(prompt);
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            if (n > 0) {
                System.out.println(starString(n));
            } else {
                System.out.print("Input must be greater than 0, try again: ");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(prompt);
        }
        System.out.println("Bye!");



        public static String starString(int n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return "*";
            } else {
                return starString(n - 1) + starString(n - 1);
            }
        }
```